# Mix C++ with C in premake4?

Tags: c++, build, premake

I am trying to use [premake4](https://premake.github.io/) to compile a `C++` `OpenGL` project. And I choose [glad](http://glad.dav1d.de/) to help me make it cross-platform.

Hence, I write the following script `premake4.lua`

```
solution "skinned-animation"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

project "skinned-animation"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    linkoptions { "-L/usr/local/lib", "-lboost_system", "-lboost_filesystem", "-lglfw" }

    includedirs { "../prerequisite", "/usr/local/include" }
    files { "../skinned-animation/**.h", "../skinned-animation/**.cpp", "../skinned-animation/**.c" }

    buildoptions { "-std=c++14" }
```

However, the problem is that `premake` will exert the flag `-std=c++14` to all both `C`(only `glad.c` actually) and `C++` files. And that leads to an error.

How can we distinguish `C` and `C++` and give them different flags because `premake4` doesn't have `filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I choose to compile `glad.c` to static library first with the following instruction and then link it to my project:

```
clang -c glad.c
ar rcs libglad.a glad.o
```